# STF File Format for Section Names on Page Layouts - Translation Workbench

Tags: community, page-layout, translation-workbench

As of now, we are doing it manually.

But does any one have idea about the format of STF file to include translations for Layout Section/Subsection names of the page layouts.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LayoutSection.OBJECTNAME.LAYOUTNAME.SECTIONNAME_SECTIONINDEX    ENGLISHTRANSLATION  TRANSLATION -

e.g
LayoutSection.Account.Account Layout.Additional Information_4   Additional Information  Zusätzliche Informationen   -